# Floated Div Overflow Scroll Browser

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that is fired on a jQuery call. I am using this css

```
.Window {
    display:none;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    z-index:1;
    min-width:500px;
    min-height:180px;
    top:20%;
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-250px
}
```

Basically the div hovers over the content in the center of the screen.  The problem is, when I place additional content within the `.Window` div and the div is taller than the browser itself, the browser window does not scroll. What would I do to make the browser window scroll so it shows the entire div with its elements inside?

Comment: Wouldn't `overflow:auto;` solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `position:fixed;` with `position:absolute;`

Comment: this will work but I have records that will dynamically be added in through jquery if the user scrolls down the page prior to firing the window. With this being said, if I open the window somewhat down the page... the window will not pop up in the center of the page but at the top. This is why I use fixed positioning

Answer (score 0):

In the parent div

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Answer (score 0):

The position:fixed place the element relative to the browser window. The div will stay in the same position. So you need to change the position property to an other.

Comment: I tried absolute but like what I said to @stewe, it isn't user friendly to what I need

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe i found something that will be useful for you. Make a div element which will cover all the screen with a css like that

```
         width:100%;
         height:100%;
         position:fixed;
         top:0;
         overflow:auto;
```

Don't put any background and don't forget the overflow.

Then in this div place your div but with relative position. The css looks like

```
    .Window {
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        z-index:1;
        width:500px;
        height:180px;
        top:20%;
        position:relative;
        margin:auto;
    }
```

With the margin:auto the element go to center horizontaly and with top go 20% from the top of the first div, ie the top of the browser.

I hope help you!!!